# Create jar from master project pom

Tags: java, android, maven, spring-boot

I want to create the jar file from the master project which has other projects as sub-modules.

I tried creating jars for the sub-modules but every module is giving me error.The master project pom is coded as pom. When I run maven clean package on this pom it gives me following console logs

```
Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ****     [pom]
[INFO] model    [jar]
[INFO] service  [jar]
[INFO] handler  [jar]
[INFO] web      [jar]

Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ******* 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ..............................SUCCESS [  0.576 
s]
[INFO] model .............................................. FAILURE [ 14.510 
s]
[INFO] service ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] handler ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] web 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler- 
plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project model: Fatal error 
compiling: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: 
com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags -> [Help 1]
```

POM for first child in the hierarchy:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>*****</artifactId>
    <groupId>******</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>model</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Redis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I want to create the jar and deploy it on AWS instance of windows server

Comment: An excellent overview of [multi module projects in maven](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obHce3gvgec). Review it, you will learn something.

Comment: @DigitalAlchemist thanks for the link, it helped and made the task complete.

Answer (score 0):

The master projects are only POMs you cannot create a jar from them. You create jars from the modules.

Comment: I know, can you please explain what are the requirements to create jars from modules? As I am to run it locally, so I assume my build path and environment is setup correctly. I am still facing issue while creating jars for modules

Comment: Could you please add the POM of one of your modules to the question?

Comment: Meir added the pom

Comment: Maybe the apt-maven-plugin does not work correctly.

Comment: Hi, now that war got deployed on the server, the application link changed. Previously I was able to access it with localhost:5000,now it is not coming up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the lombok version. I was using 1.16.18, when i changed it to 1.18.10, the problem got resolved